# How to port chrome extension functionality to mobile (Specifically jquery and trello)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, google-chrome-extension

I've built myself a pretty handy chrome extension for trello that allows me to copy a list in plaintext to the clipboard, which for some reason isn't already a thing. It's going great and I want to hand it out to my teammates because we communicate through slack and text messages, but organize on trello.

It just hit me that a couple of my teammates use trello primarily on their phones, and the ability to text a list to a non-member would be WAAAAAAY more handy than having to open up a laptop to do it.

I'm definitely aware that chrome mobile won't allow extensions in the foreseeable future and my team doesn't want to shell out for trello business class just for a simple 'power up'. **Until then, is there any way to add functionality/inject javascript to a web app on mobile?**

Answer (score 1):

You could write a bookmarklet using the `javascript:` protocol. That's what I do for fairly simple stuff in mobile Safari. You just click the bookmarklet while you're on the page in question to execute some JavaScript. For example:

```js
var script = document.getElementById('script');
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');

function update(){
  loader.textContent = (
    encodeURIComponent(`!function(){var d,s=(d=document).createElement('script');s.src="${encodeURI(decodeURI(script.value))}";d.head.appendChild(s)}()`)
  );
}

script.addEventListener('update', update);

update();
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello%20World')">Hello World</a>
<br/>
<input id="script" value="https://pastebin.com/raw/gxCbGimA"/>
<br/>
<a href="javascript:!function()%7Bvar%20d%2Cs%3D(d%3Ddocument).createElement('script')%3Bs.src%3Dd.getElementById('script').value%3Bd.head.appendChild(s)%7D()">Run Script</a>
<br/>
<textarea id="loader"></textarea>
```

For the record, these are the scripts:

```
alert("Hello World");
```

```
!function(){
  var d,s=(d=document).createElement('script');
  s.src=d.getElementById('script').value;
  d.head.appendChild(s)
}()
```

You can save links like that as a mobile bookmarklet to execute whenever they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

answer is: no, you cant inject or modify pages in mobile.
currently your only option is to make an app for android and another one for iOS. The task is easier than you think of you use Cordova to write a javascript app.

source: Im the maker of the Plus for Trello extension (and Android app :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox for Android supports extensions, and there are at least a few extensions available that enable user script functionality, e.g. [USI](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/userunified-script-injector/).